# Why I'm unable to use sum() method here, while I am able to use '+' operator?

Tags: python

This is the class. I am using.

```
class Shirt:

def __init__(self, shirt_color, shirt_size, shirt_style, shirt_price):
    self.color = shirt_color
    self.size = shirt_size
    self.style = shirt_style
    self.price = shirt_price

def change_price(self, new_price):

    self.price = new_price
    
def discount(self, discount):

    return self.price * (1 - discount)
```

I created two objects of it:-

```
shirt_one = Shirt('red', 'S', 'long-sleeve', 25)
shirt_two = Shirt('orange', 'L', 'short-sleeve', 10)
```

When I try to use sum() it fails and throws an error. **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

```
total = sum(shirt_one.price, shirt_two.price)
print(total)
```

But when I use the '+' operator It works it works fine.

```
total = shirt_one.price + shirt_two.price
print(total)
```

Comment: `sum` takes an *iterable* (a list or such), it doesn’t take two single arguments to sum. Because there’s already `+` for that.

Comment: You are confused with ```sum```. You need an iterable for sum. Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-function-python/).

Comment: You can do `sum([shirt_one.price, shirt_two.price])`

Comment: Does anyone know why `min` and `max` accept both forms (an iterable or multiple arguments),  but `sum` does not?

Comment: @VPfB Because both use cases are common for that: `max(a, b)` and `max(lst)`. But for `sum`, the first case is already handled by `+`, and `sum` *does* accept a second argument, but that has another meaning, so `sum(a, b)` would become ambiguous and just complicate the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing an error because the `sum()` function expects an iterable object (example: lists) while you're passing in integer values.

Try running `sum(1,2)` and notice that the same error shows up, while running `sum([1,2])` will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The sum() function takes an iterable as the argument and sums over it, it doesn't add the arguments.

See for example : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 1):

That is because according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) ,
the function definition is

`sum(iterable, /, start=0)`

which means that you need to pass an iterable(like a list, tuple, etc) for it to sum all the elements in that iterable.

What you are trying to do is an operator overload of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum()` function returns a number, the sum of all items in an iterable.
You must know what this function do it gives iterable for first arguemnt you must give this function a iterable.
For example:

```py
iterable_example = (1 , 2 , 3 , 4)
print(sum(iterable_example))
```

Output : `10`